# Can you remove the "Via _Application_" on Facebook wall posts via the API?

Tags: facebook

I ask because some of my users have made complaints that they want their comments sent to friends to look authentic. Thank you.

Comment: please don't. it's bad enough that apps are allowed to spam walls. the 'via application' link at the bottom of the post is how you get to the page to block the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... I looked into this and it is not possible via the API. For anyone else out there struggling with this issue here are the different advices I've uncovered:

1. You can set your logo to a white box which hides that visual element from the Via line.
2. You can ask your users for their username/password and scrape/post data as you wish, but use the FB App as a jump-off for user buy-in.
3. You can pick the most subtle name possible. Today, FB requires 6 or 7 characters for the app name.